# How could residuals be equal to 0?

Tags: r

I'm doing a very simple linear regression model, but for some of my variables, I get the following kind of output.
Could you please help me to find out what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
lm(formula = Age ~ L.1.HU + L.1.V + L.2.HU + L.2.V + L.3.HU + 
    L.3.V + L.4.HU + L.4.V + L.5.HU + L.5.V, data = CT)

Residuals:
ALL 11 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 88.106023         NA      NA       NA
L.1.HU      -0.049377         NA      NA       NA
L.1.V        0.169878         NA      NA       NA
L.2.HU      -0.052153         NA      NA       NA
L.2.V       -0.367214         NA      NA       NA
L.3.HU      -0.038905         NA      NA       NA
L.3.V        0.378833         NA      NA       NA
L.4.HU      -0.001531         NA      NA       NA
L.4.V       -0.923230         NA      NA       NA
L.5.HU       0.150823         NA      NA       NA
L.5.V        0.871423         NA      NA       NA
```

Comment: You are using 11 data points to fit a model with 11 terms, thus making an exact fit with no information left over to estimate the quality of the fit.

Comment: Hi Maria, maybe you want to elaborate on is your dataset and what you would like to know from it?

Comment: @StupidWolf this dataset consists of 13 variables: sex, age and 11 measurements of density and volumes. I would like to figure out if there is any correlation between the age and the density and volume. Do you think I'm on the right track?

Comment: Ok, do you mean there's 11 measurements of density, 11 measurements of volumes and 11 corresponding ages?

Comment: @MariaKischenko, It is difficult to provide an exact answer without understanding the data collected.  Assuming you currently have 11 individuals with 11 measurements each, yes are on the correct track. BUT for a model this complex, with 11 terms, you will need to gather a lot more data in order to make a good fit and draw conclusions from the model.  If you can't collect more data, then consider simplifying your model with less terms.

Comment: @StupidWolf jep sorry it might not be clear... It means 5 observations, for each observation I have a measurement of density and measurement of volume

Comment: @Dave2e It is going to be around 200 individuals. I'm just trying to establish a good model which can further be used

Comment: I see. it's clear now. Your data is in the wrong format to start with. Is it going to be like this for 200 individuals?

Comment: If i get you correct, what you have above is for 1 individual, and you take 5 measures of density and volume. Your data is in the wrong format to start with. Is it going to be like this for 200 individuals, or you will have 200 such rows?

Comment: @StupidWolf it is going to be 200 such individuals, not rows. How the format should be?

Comment: @StupidWolf   **Number Age Sex L.1.HU L.1.V L.2.HU L.2.V L.3.HU L.3.V L.4.HU L.4.V L.5.HU L.5.V (those are columns)